# Understanding Reactive Extensions and CallContext

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I have code that uses CallContext to transport session information to Task continuations. Now I've introduced use of Reactive Extensions, and I'm observing some odd behavior that I'd like to understand.

I have this helper class that wraps usage of CallContext.

```
public static class TestContext
{
    private static readonly string _KEY = "my-context";

    public static int Value
    {
        get { return CallContext.LogicalGetData(_KEY) as int? ?? -1; }
        set { CallContext.LogicalSetData(_KEY, value); }
    }
}
```

In my main function, I create a cold observable using interval. On each tick, I project the context value to see what context is present in the pipeline.

```
var periodic = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), Scheduler.Default)
    .Select(_ => TestContext.Value)
    .Timestamp();
```

In a loop, I set the context to the loop index, and then subscribe and dump out the sequence using LINQPad's DumpLatest method. For fun, I set the context to a different value (42) at the end of the iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    TestContext.Value = i;
    periodic
        .DumpLatest(string.Format("Iteration {0}", i));
    TestContext.Value = 42;
}
```

I expect each subscription to capture the context from subscribe time. I expect subscription notifications to match the subscription iteration number.

This works exactly as expected when my scheduler is Scheduler.Default, as coded above.

[image: With Scheduler.Default]

However, if I change the scheduler to `new EventLoopScheduler()` all subscriptions use the same context.

```
var periodic = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), new EventLoopScheduler())
    .Select(_ => TestContext.Value)
    .Timestamp();
```

[image: With EventLoopScheduler]

Why does Scheduler.Default propagate the CallContext as I expect, while EventLoopScheduler doesn't?

Thanks,
Ranj

Comment: `CallContext` seems to be a thread-aware value. So it seems strange that it works with `Scheduler.Default`. I don't know enough about `CallContext` to comment why.

Comment: Agreed. The `Interval` operator requires concurrency. Somehow, `Scheduler.Default` is successfully transporting `CallContext` from the subscriber thread to the pipeline thread.